# Jenkins declarative pipeline: use branch if it exist

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I'm currently trying to adopt my declarative pipeline in the following way:

I have multiple stages, some apply for all branches, some only for specific names.

What I'm now searching for is a way to get a when condition for the existance of a branch like this:

```
if branch b exist
   checkout branch b
else
   checkout branch a
```

Sadly I haven't found a solution for it. I'm pretty sure there is a way using the **git plugin** though.

There's a [StackOverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508326/jenkins-git-branch-selection-with-fallback/48579241#comment86569907_48579241) for scripted pipelines, but I can't translate them though.

Can someone help me with this or point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using [Declarative Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) you can achieve the goal of running some steps only for certain branches by using the [when directive](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) with the build-in condition `branch`:

> **`branch`** Execute the stage when the branch being built matches the branch pattern (ANT style path glob) given, for example: when { branch 'master' }. Note that this only works on a multibranch Pipeline.

```java
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages { 
        stage("Build") {
            when { branch "master" }
            steps { 
               echo "I am a master branch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you use Scripted Pipeline, you may also access the `BRANCH_NAME` from environment variable and do something with it:

```java
if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
   //do something
}
```

Also have a look at [Flow Control](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#flow-control) to understand how you can control the flow of your pipeline.

Comment: `env.BRANCH_NAME` is not always available. Use `steps { sh 'printenv'}` to check.

Answer (score 5):

There's a [`resolveScm` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#resolvescm-resolves-an-scm-from-an-scm-source-and-a-list-of-candidate-target-branch-names) implemented by the [Pipeline: Multibranch plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/):

```
checkout resolveScm(source: [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
                             credentialsId: '<credentialsId>',
                             id: '_',
                             remote: 'https://your.git.remote/repository.git',
                             traits: [[$class: 'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait']]],
                    targets: [BRANCH_NAME, 'master'])
```

Above procedure will look whether `$BRANCH_NAME` exists, check it out if yes and check out `master` otherwise.

Comment: This is not declarative but could be run in a script block. Declarative pipelines typically do not include a checkout function in a multibranch pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is easier to ask forgiveness than permission.

Instead of trying to figure out whether branch `b` exists, just try to check it out.

If it fails, checkout branch `a`.

```
script {
    try {
        checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: 'b']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: url]]
        ])
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        checkout([
                $class: 'GitSCM',
                branches: [[name: 'a']],
                userRemoteConfigs: [[url: url]]
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, but you will probably not get the expected result if the checkout fails for any reason other than the branch not existing...

Answer (score 1):

```
pipeline {
  agent any 
  stages { 
    stage('Tests') {
      when {
        branch 'master'
      }
      steps {
        echo 'foo'
      } 
   }
}
```